# Java - How to get the double from an Integer (Money)

Tags: java, algorithm, currency

I got:

```
int number = 1255; -> //It could also be 125(1€25Cent) or 10(10Cent) or 5(5Cent)

public double toMoney(int number)
{
...
}
```

as return, I want the double number: **12.55** or if input: 10 then: **00.10**

I know that I can do with Modulo something like this:

1255 % 100.. to get 55.. But how to do it for 12 and at the end, how to 
form it as a double?

Comment: You shouldn't use double for money values, bad idea.

Comment: I'm learning (school) and its a part of the exercise

Comment: @PetrAbdulin out of curiosity, what should one use then?

Comment: @Kshitij: BigDecimal or String. The main point is that `double` simply does not *have* decimal places, because it's not a decimal format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're probably trying to just do this:

```
return (double)number / 100.;
```

**Though a word of warning:** *You shouldn't be using floating-point for money due to round-off issues.*

If you just want to print the number in money format, here's a 100% safe method:

```
System.out.print((number / 100) + ".");
int cents = number % 100;
if (cents < 10)
    System.out.print("0");
System.out.println(cents);
```

This can probably be simplified a lot better... Of course you can go with BigDecimal, but IMO that's smashing an ant with a sledgehammer.

Comment: I guess for a homework assignment, you can probably get away with it. But in general, it's best to leave it as an integer representing Cents.

Comment: Yes, but I have to make a Method (printMoney) which prints the money in this format: XX.XX € or whatever.. so I need the "Transformer"^^

Comment: it wasnt complete, i just added the same 4 Euro.. : `int euro = pGeldWertGanzzahl / 100;
  if (euro < 10)
   System.out.print("0");
  System.out.print((euro) + ".");
  
  int cents = pGeldWertGanzzahl % 100;
  if (cents < 10)
      System.out.print("0");
  System.out.println(cents);` thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**That method should not exist, because it cannot give correct results.**

Because internally, `double` is a format (binary floating-point) that cannot accurately represent a number like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 *at all*. Read the [Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/) for more information.

**If you need decimals, your output format should be `BigDecimal` or `String`.**

Comment: yes thats right.. I got numbers like 0.1, but I would like to have 00.10 ..  But when I type in BigDecimal, it tells me, that the type is not recognized..

Comment: @eMi `BigDecimal` is a class and you need to import it.

Comment: @eMi: leading zeroes are really are about formatting, so you have to use DecimalFormat to get a String.

Answer (score 4):

The way printing money amounts should be done is by using NumberFormat class!

Check out this example:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
format.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("EUR"));
System.out.println( format.format(13234.34) );
```

Which print this output:

```
13 234,34 €
```

You can try different locales and currency codes. See docs: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html.

Answer (score 2):

```
public double toMoney(int number)
{
  return number / 100.0;
}
```

If you're dealing with monetary amounts, do bear in mind that some loss of precision can occur when you convert the number to a `double`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public double toMoney(int number)
{
return number / 100.0
}
```

The trick is to use `100.0` rather than `100` to force java to use double division.

Answer (score 2):

```
public double toMoney(int number)
{
    return number / 100.0;
}
```

P.S. You shouldn't use double for money values, bad idea.

Comment: look at answer: `int euro = number/ 100; if (euro < 10) System.out.print("0"); System.out.print((euro) + "."); int cents = number% 100; if (cents < 10) System.out.print("0"); System.out.println(cents);` that worked